# How to reshape last layer of pytorch CNN model while doing transfer learning

Tags: keras, neural-network, pytorch, transfer-learning

Actually i am trying to replicate keras structure to pytorch.(new in pytorch).
Here is keras architecture

```
base_model = InceptionV3(weights='imagenet', include_top=False)
x = base_model.output
x = Dense(512, activation='relu')(x)
predictions = Dense(49*6,activation='sigmoid')(x)
reshape=Reshape((49,6))(predictions)
model = Model(inputs=base_model.input, outputs=reshape)
for layer in base_model.layers:
    layer.trainable = False
```

I want to reshape last layer of my netwrok. I have implemented transfer learning.

```
model =  models.inception_v3(pretrained=True)

for param in model.parameters():
    param.requires_grad = False

num_ftrs = model.fc.in_features
```

I believe if i can attach last layer of resnet with my following architecture, problem can be solved. But i dont know how i can attach them

```
class CNN(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(CNN, self).__init__()
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(num_ftrs, 512)
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(512, 49*6)

    def forward(self, x):
        print (x.shape)
        x = x.view(-1,num_ftrs)
        #print (x.shape)
        x = F.relu(self.fc1(x))
        x = self.fc2(x)
        x=torch.sigmoid(x.view(49,6))
        return x
```

Any idea, how this problem can be resolved

Comment: It's not very clear what your asking or what your problem is. That said from initial inspection of your code it seems to me you probably want `num_ftrs = model.fc.out_features` and since theirs a batch dimension in the output you probably want to use `x.view(-1, 49, 6))` during forward instead of `x.view(49, 6)`

Comment: You need to pass `num_ftrs` into your `__init__`. After that there are a couple ways to connect the networks. The easiest is probably just define another model which is an instance of `CNN`, maybe like `model_cnn = CNN(num_ftrs)` then pass the output of the inception network through this as follows...`output = model_cnn(model(data))`. You could also just wrap `model` and `model_cnn` in a single `torch.nn.Sequential` model.